# Repeated password requests on Ubuntu after reboot. Sudo/admin privileges seem to be revoked after reboot

Tags: permissions, sudo

I am running Jakeday's Surface Pro Ubuntu build and I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

Each time I reboot, when I log in to my admin user I get 4 prompts, two each (shown below), for my password.

```
System policy prevents control of network connections 
An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. Authentication as one of the users below is required to perform this action

Authentication is required to create a color managed device 
An application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. Authentication as one of the users below is required to perform this action
```

I am also prompted for admin password when opening network manager, when I plug in a USB and several other tasks. I have also noticed that in settings that I cannot unlock my users. I reviewed my groups and I appear to be a member of admin and sudo. And my sudo password works when I enter it for the prompts. I checked ownership of my /home directory and found no issues there.

I can log in and out of my user several times and eventually (the number of log in / log out varies) the prompts stop and I have access/permission to all elements listed above.

I use Chrome Remote Desktop, and I set it up following these instructions: https://superuser.com/questions/778028/configuring-chrome-remote-desktop-with-ubuntu-gnome-14-04/850359#850359

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu on a different partition and I did not encounter the issue, but I also did not reinstall all the programs I have on my current primary use partition. I recently started encountering the same issue on a desktop I have set up at work.

I would really like to avoid a fresh install, and I use Chrome Remote Desktop regularly. I have spent three weeks reading through suggestions with no luck. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I don't think re-installing is going to help: access to these resources is managed by PolicyKit, which has different rules for non-local versus local sessions. There's quite a good discussion (albeit with a focus on xRDP rather than Chrome Remote Desktop) at [xRDP – The Infamous “Authentication Required to Create Managed Color Device” Explained](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073)

Comment: I actually reviewed that exact post and did my best to understand the role of PolicyKit. I foolishly thought maybe I edited something that caused the problem so I uninstalled PolicyKit and all dependent items. HA HA what a mistake. Took me two days to rebuild my missing components. I'm at a total loss. I don't even know how to pinpoint the issue, so any new lead you could give would be very much appreciated!